# play video from www folder using html video tag ( on android )

Tags: android, html, cordova, video

I'm using the following code to display a video

```
<video id="v1" class="no-fastclick" controls>
    <source class="no-fastclick" src="img/home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Actually "nearly" everything works. The Video is playable but  I only have sound. However, when making it fullscreen I also see the video. So everything seems to be right - except that it doesn't show up when not being in full screen.

I cannot found a method to force the fullscreen on click or make it playable in small version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

After discussing with the OP in the comments below, I built a test app and uploaded it for the OP.

I have confirmed the video works on an actual device. Having tried the same app on the emulator I was able to reproduce the issue. It would seem that this is an emulator issue and not an issue with Cordova or actual devices.

**Edit**

It seems you are not the only one having this issue. There is a plugin that should enable video tags to work properly here:

https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video/blob/master/README.md

Installation:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video.git
```

Sample usage:

```
<video id="myvideo" loop></video>
```

Hopefully this will work!

**Original**

You may need to add the webkit-playsinline attribute like this example:

```
<video webkit-playsinline>
    <source src="mySource.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Also you may need to add this to your config.xml

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with information regarding a plugin for this. It seems chrome webview doesn't like playing video from content://

Comment: I've already tried this one aswell. I have the feelingt he cordova community is somehow dead. I cannot find any working example for playing the stupid video directly. I really cant understnd why it's working in fullscreen. I'd be totally fine if it always plays in fullscreen but even that is not working -.-

Comment: I am stumped! Just built a test app to see if I could recreate the problem and the video plays fine inline and in fullscreen. Sorry I cant help further I just can recreate the issue.

Comment: what video did you use? What version of android / cordova did you use?

Comment: Cordova 6.5.0 Android 7.0. video was downloaded from here http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4 I can test on an older version of Android if you need me to.

Comment: I'm using the exact same version. Running the app in an emulator ... Can you somehow provide your project to me? I removed everything and made an empty index.html only with video and it is still not working. can't believe this

Comment: I have upload the project and a screen recording of the app on my device: Here is the link for the video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3JK7HmVuvg0LTJLb0ZmWTNjXzQ Here is the link for the project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3JK7HmVuvg0d1dNbmo1RFExSEE

Comment: got it running - but didnt play the video. Maybe because of the emulator?

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect that I too have tried the app I uploaded on an emulator and was able to reproduce your error. Looks like its an emulator issue.

Comment: oh wow thanks then I think your answer is then correct after all :) Really really big thanks for the long support mate!

Comment: No problem I love these kinds of problems and I always learn something new when trying to find the problem. We got there in the end!

Comment: Maybe a minor update : I only have a 4.4.2 android device currently and the video is not playing there aswell. I've sent it to a friend with android 5 and it was working. My first wild guess would be that it only works on android > 5

Comment: Yeah. Not sure but i think on Android < 5 you may need the html5video plugin I referenced in my answer. I think older versions of chrome webview probably lack full support for video tags. How annoying. If you need further help feel free to email me leebalsdon1988@gmail.com

Comment: A final update as comment: I didn't manage to get the video running with the plugin you referenced - however I got it running using crosswalks ( https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview ) - I did not yet add it to my actual app, however - at least the video was finally playing :) !