# HTML5 Video Player Android - PhoneGAP

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, html5-video

I am new to Android development and Hybrid Mobile Application, but I need to play video inside my Hybrid Mobile Application. I am using HTML5 native video tag and I can confirm that it works fine on IOS.

What happens on Android Phones is when you press the play button, the screen lefts empty and I can see in the logs the following lines:

```html
04-27 10:25:58.208 1655-2941/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2803c75org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@a83940a req=3flags=0x0
04-27 10:25:58.210 3082-3082/com.example W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/demovideos/video.mp4
04-27 10:25:58.217 1361-3333/? D/NuPlayer: onSetVideoSurface(0xf3d20100, no video decoder)
04-27 10:25:58.402 3082-3241/com.example E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1642)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:F89A7C82A67F0000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
04-27 10:25:58.647 1361-3334/? I/SampleTable: There are reordered frames present.
04-27 10:25:58.649 1361-3333/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xf3d45540), (5, 320, 240)
04-27 10:25:58.650 1361-3333/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xf3d45540), (3, 17, 0)
04-27 10:25:58.954 1361-3339/? I/NuCachedSource2: caching reached eos.
04-27 10:25:59.649 1361-3333/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xf3d45540), (3, 100, 0)
04-27 10:25:59.649 1361-3333/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xf3d45540), (1, 0, 0)
04-27 10:25:59.745 3082-3082/com.example D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
04-27 10:25:59.777 1361-1652/? D/NuPlayerDriver: start(0xf3d45540), state is 4, eos is 0
04-27 10:25:59.777 1361-3333/? I/GenericSource: start
```

I have looked inside stackoverflow.com and read all the comments and recommendations,

- Setting WebChrome Client and
- Enabling Hardware Accelerator in my AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="30306" android:versionName="3.3.6" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.example" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.MyApplication">
        ... 
        ...
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have also checked the content type and the size of my video (1MB):

```html
http GET https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/demovideos/video.mp4

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1065903
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 00:00:58 GMT
ETag: "c866e6fe66f12efed2df2db39d9b2f67"
Last-Modified: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 00:00:55 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-amz-request-id: xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Node: 
 - The App is written in HTML5 and with PhoneGAP Wrapped.

I really appreciate if you can give me any clue of why it doesn't work. Please don't send the Stackoverflow link, I have already tried all of them.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [play video from www folder using html video tag ( on android )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559572/play-video-from-www-folder-using-html-video-tag-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559947/7837081

We found there is an issue if you are trying to use video tags on an emulator. Also there is a problem with video takes on Android versions =< 4.4.2

Comment: The screen is blank, the video is playing and I can hear the sound. Please check the attachment.   http://imgur.com/a/QZcH3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, we found out that someone disable hardware accelation in the code by calling:

this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html